# Symfony logs out every few mins and ignores lifetime

Tags: symfony

just recently I noticed that Symfony logs me out from my application when idle for a few mins. It's odd because when I first refresh the screen it looks like I'm still logged in however when I refresh the second time it redirects to the login form. To prevent that I added the "lifetime" parameter however it seems to be ignored. Can you please provide the best practice to troubleshoot this issue?

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: /
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
            # by default, the feature is enabled by checking a
            # checkbox in the login form (see below), uncomment the
            # following line to always enable it.
            #always_remember_me: true
```

Comment: Which session storage are you using? Have you aligned the PHP session configuration with your requirements? Which Symfony version are you using? Which FOS User Bundle version are you using?

Comment: `logout: true`? Shouldn't this contain `path` and `target`?